# kcachegrind for RHEL 5.1

Tags: c++, profiling, valgrind, kcachegrind

I'm about to perform profiling to application. I have vagrind, but kcachegrind  is not installed.
Tryied to compile without success.

Where it can be obtained from for RHEL 5.1?

Comment: Why did it fail to compile from sources?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can get it from Debian, and convert it to RPM

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a performance problem to find? [This is a simple way to do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)